# Can I add app folders to dock from launchpad?

Tags: mac, macos

I want to add folder from launchpad, is it possible? I tried but coulndt put anyway. Is there an app or anything for this?

Answer (score 1):

Folders can be added to dock but they must be added to the right of the separator bar. Apps go to the left of the bar and files/folders to the right. The separator bar is the small verticle line on the dock. Dragging a folder onto the dock, to the right of separator bar, will attach an alias of that folder to the dock.

Comment: I know that, but also I am not talking about Finder folders. "add folder from Launchpad" means app folders.